# Updating pandas DataFrame according to columns not index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is probably a stupid beginner's question but I simply cannot figure it out after trying many different ways.

I have two pandas DataFrames. They look like the following:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["x","y","z","val0","val1"])
df0 = df0.append({"x":0,"y":0,"z":0,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":0,"y":0,"z":1,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":0,"y":1,"z":0,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":0,"y":1,"z":1,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":1,"y":0,"z":0,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":1,"y":0,"z":1,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":1,"y":1,"z":0,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
df0 = df0.append({"x":1,"y":1,"z":1,"val0":0,"val1":0}, ignore_index=True)
```

and

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["x","y","z","val0","val1"])
df1 = df1.append({"x":0,"y":1,"z":0,"val0":2,"val1":2}, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append({"x":1,"y":0,"z":1,"val0":4,"val1":4}, ignore_index=True)
```

As you can imagine, `x`, `y`, and `z` serve as "coordinates" for the two value columns `val0` and `val1`. So I want to replace the values in `df0` by the ones given in `df1` according to the coordinates and not the DF-internal index. Because, if I just run `df0.update(df1)`, the first two lines (with coordinates `000` and `001`) are replaced and, of course, also the values for `x`, `y`, and `z` are replaced such that I end up with two lines for `010` and `101`. If I use `df0.merge(df1)` I end up with sort-of the intersection of the two, so only two lines and both sets of values survive.

How do I do this properly then?
And even more: how do I do it properly for a variable set of columns/coordinates? In my use case, the data frames are built from a list of columns (which can change per scenario, of course `df0` and `df1` are built in the same way though) and a boolean flag per element that tells me whether a column of a given name is a coordinate or value.

Any advice would be welcomed.

Thank you!

c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want update `val0` and `val1` according `x`, `y` and `z`, you can use `.merge` + `.update`:

```py
df0.update(df0[["x", "y", "z"]].merge(df1, on=["x", "y", "z"], how="left"))
print(df0)
```

Prints:

```
   x  y  z val0 val1
0  0  0  0    0    0
1  0  0  1    0    0
2  0  1  0    2    2
3  0  1  1    0    0
4  1  0  0    0    0
5  1  0  1    4    4
6  1  1  0    0    0
7  1  1  1    0    0
```

Comment: Oh, it's that easy! Thanks so much, works briliantly!